# How to tokenize using regular expression such that regex for "everything else" does not match regex for "special tokens"?

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I have the following kind of text that I want to tokenize.

Text:

```
<!-- foo-bar --> Text1 <!-!> <!-- bar-baz --> Text2
```

I want to tokenize it into three kinds of tokens, `COMMENT_START`, `COMMENT_END` and `OTHER`.

For example, for the above text, I want the following output.

```
COMMENT_START <!--
OTHER  foo-bar 
COMMENT_END -->
OTHER  Text1 <!-!>
COMMENT_START <!--
OTHER  bar-baz
COMMENT_END -->
OTHER Text2
```

Inspired by https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer I wrote this program.

```
import re

def tokenize(code):
    token_specification = [
        ('COMMENT_START', '<!--'),
        ('COMMENT_END', '-->'),
        ('OTHER', '.*')
    ]

    tok_regex = '|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specification)

    for mo in re.finditer(tok_regex, code):
        kind = mo.lastgroup
        value = mo.group(kind)
        print(kind, value)

test_string = '<!-- foo-bar --> Text1 <!-!> <!-- bar-baz --> Text2'
tokenize(test_string)
```

But it doesn't give the desired output. This is the output I get.

```
COMMENT_START <!--
OTHER  foo-bar --> Text1 <!-!> <!-- bar-baz --> Text2
OTHER
```

The problem is that the regular expression for `OTHER` is consuming the entire string.

The regular expression for `OTHER` is meant to match everything else apart from the special tokens such as `<!--` and `-->`.

How can I write this program properly that the regular expression for `OTHER` does not consume `<!--` or `-->` and leave it alone so that they can later get matched by the regular expressions for `COMMENT_START` and `COMMENT_END`?

More generally, how to write a tokenizer that can yield the special tokens we are interested in as well as everything else as tokens too?

Comment: I had the very exact problem. In my case I have a human-entered text in a CRM and I want to a) substitute IDs in the form of a sha1 result into links to that entity, b) subsituting everything that ressembles a link to a clickable link and c) convert `<` and `>` to the printable strings `&lt;` and `&gt;`. I asked here https://stackoverflow.com/q/68988193/1315009 and the answer @rici gave suggested a Left-To-Right parser. Then I had this very exact problem you describe: Tokens "ID", "LINK" and "HTML-CHAR" and then "ANYTHING-ELSE": https://stackoverflow.com/q/69059734/1315009

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `other` expression will match anything, even a comment.  To get around this, you have two options.  One is to make `other` match just one character, and then later collapse strings of "others" into a single "other".  Like this:

```
token_specification = [
    ('COMMENT_START', '<!--'),
    ('COMMENT_END', '-->'),
    ('OTHER', '.')
]
```

The output then is:

```
COMMENT_START <!--
OTHER  
OTHER f
OTHER o
OTHER o
OTHER  
COMMENT_END -->
OTHER  
OTHER T
OTHER e
OTHER x
OTHER t
OTHER 1
(etc. . . .)
```

By matching just one character in "other", you give it a chance to look for a comment at every position.  You'd then have to iterate over the token list and combine consecutive "other" tokens.

The other way is to make your `other` non-greedy and include a lookahead for the other token types:

```
token_specification = [
    ('COMMENT_START', '<!--'),
    ('COMMENT_END', '-->'),
    ('OTHER', r'.*?(?=-->|<!--)')
]
```

This gives your desired output:

```
COMMENT_START <!--
OTHER  foo 
COMMENT_END -->
OTHER  Text1 
COMMENT_START <!--
OTHER  bar 
COMMENT_END -->
```

However, this solution is less extensible because you have to repeat the other tokens inside `other`.  If you had more kinds of tokens, this would become unwieldy.

I'd recommend you take a look at parsing libraries like [parcon](http://www.opengroove.org/parcon/) or [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/), which are better suited for doing this sort of parsing than are plain regexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:(?!<!--|-->).)*
```

Use these as `other`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sD1lU8/5

Comment: `OTHER` may contain the characters `!`, `<`, `>` and `-`. `OTHER` must not contain the string `<!--`. `OTHER` must not contain the string `-->`.

Comment: @LoneLearner check demo.